# Submit Form with method="get" in Typo3 Backend module gives error

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have made one typo3 backend module and included one form with method "get" in view file. but when i try to submit form i get following error.[image]

I have also tried with method="post" and it works fine.
If any one have idea regarding this, please share.
Thanks

Recently I used one of TER extension name "ics_awstats/", same problem of invalid token occurs when i use full list pages form.

Please see second attachment.

Initially there was not any method specify in form, so I added `method="post"` in `ics_awstats/awstats/awstats.pl` this file and problem gets solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 uses hidden/automatic generated fields in forms to verify proper usage.
If you change the form-method to get you might remove some parameters from the action-url.

The other possible reason could be: you can not transfer so much data in get-parameters than in post-parameters. maybe you exhaust the limit of 2KB for URL and URL-Parameters

Comment: I have passed only one parameter "id" in form.

Comment: have a look at the action url if you use POST (what parameter also occur?) and have also cookies in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 6.2, links to backend modules are signed with a CSRF token which has to be part of the URL parameters of course. The utility method `BackendUtility::getModuleUrl()` is capable of creating a proper CSRF-signed URL. Find more details in the [form-protection documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormProtection/).

For example, the URL to the extension manager looks like this in TYPO3 6.2
`/typo3/mod.php?M=tools_ExtensionmanagerExtensionmanager&moduleToken=2f1f29410c79fe063d126f603afa0f993591ad32`.

The URL to your custom backend module should look similar concerning the parameters.